# fastLED help - special reinforcements needed

Tags: led

Hello help needed trying to get fastLED to start and stop at specific points on the strip, i have this nice fade animation but need to split the strip intov about 3 sections and have it run at different times.

here is the mess i have made any help welcome...

```cpp
#include <FastLED.h>
#define NUM_LEDS 60
#define DATA_PIN 6 //How boring and obvious!
#define COLOR_ORDER GRB //Green (G), Red (R), Blue (B)
#define CHIPSET WS2812B
#define BRIGHTNESS 60
#define VOLTS 5
#define MAX_AMPS 500 //value in milliamps

//ENOUGH NONSENSE!

CRGB leds[NUM_LEDS];

void setup() {
  FastLED.addLeds<CHIPSET,DATA_PIN,COLOR_ORDER>(leds, NUM_LEDS);
  FastLED.setMaxPowerInVoltsAndMilliamps(VOLTS, MAX_AMPS);
  FastLED.setBrightness(BRIGHTNESS);
  FastLED.clear();
  FastLED.show(); 
}

void loop() {
  fadeToBlackBy(leds, NUM_LEDS, 4);      // Smaller value = longer tail
  int i = (millis()/40) % NUM_LEDS;      // How fast it goes.
  leds[i] = CRGB::White;
  FastLED.show();
}
```

Cheers
Rob

Comment: Any idea how i can set a start led and end led position that is not the full lengh of the strip?

my micky mouse version ...
for(int i=40; i<strip.numPixels() -43; i++) { // For each pixel in strip...

i edit the "i=40" bit then the "-43;"

Comment: do you realize that you can write code like this? ... `for(int i=start; i<end; i++)`

Comment: Ok very sorry first time on here ill edit the question.

Comment: how about something like this https://wokwi.com/projects/362275278547275777

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example sketch that shows how to manipulate data in a sub-section of an array.

https://wokwi.com/projects/362275278547275777

The important thing to understand, is that the `FastLED.show();` is the function that does the sending of the `leds[]` array contents to the physical LED strip.

That means that you can do anything you want to the `leds[]` array, and the changes will not be visible until the `show()` function is called.

You can make changes in bits and pieces, without seeing the change increments.

This sketch also shows how to use timers to synchronize actions

```c++
#include <FastLED.h>

#define CHIPSET     WS2812B
#define COLOR_ORDER     GRB         // Green (G), Red (R), Blue (B)
#define NUM_LEDS         95
#define DATA_PIN          3
#define BRIGHTNESS      255
#define VOLTS             5
#define MAX_AMPS        500         // value in milliamps

CRGB leds[NUM_LEDS];                // main LED array
CRGB test[10];                      // set up separate array for merging with main LED array
                                    // kind of a sprite
int indx = 0;

boolean tick[4] = {false, false, false, false};    // countdown timers flags

unsigned long timeInterval  [4] = {10, 20, 1, 2};  // timers load with these values
unsigned long timeCounter   [4];                   // these are the actual timers

unsigned long previousMicros = 0;


void setup() {

  Serial.begin(115200);

  FastLED.addLeds<CHIPSET,DATA_PIN,COLOR_ORDER>(leds, NUM_LEDS);
  FastLED.setMaxPowerInVoltsAndMilliamps(VOLTS, MAX_AMPS);
  FastLED.setBrightness(BRIGHTNESS);
  FastLED.clear();

  memcpy(timeCounter, timeInterval, 4 * sizeof(long));  // preload timers
}

void loop() {

  unsigned long currentMicros = micros();

  if (currentMicros - previousMicros >= 1000) {   // 1 ms tick
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      previousMicros = currentMicros;

      timeCounter[i]-- ;                          // keep track of 4 time intervals
      if (timeCounter[i] == 0) {
        timeCounter[i] = timeInterval[i];         // reached zero, reload counter and emit a "tick"
        tick[i] = true;
      }
    }

    // fade sections of leds[] array at different rates
    // NOTE: "&leds[0]" and "leds" both point to the beginning of the array
    fadeToBlackBy(&leds [0], 30,  3);               //  long tail
    fadeToBlackBy(&leds[30], 30, 10);               //   mid tail
    fadeToBlackBy(&leds[60], 30, 20);               // short tail
    fadeToBlackBy(&leds[90],  5,  1);               // really long tail

    if (tick[0]) {    // 10 ms tick
      tick[0] = false;
      leds[indx] = CRGB::White;                   // add the "running dot" after fades are applied
      indx++;
      if (indx > (NUM_LEDS-1)) indx = 0;
    }

    if (tick[1]) {    // 20 ms tick
      tick[1] = false;

//    the &test[0] points to the array element directly
//    it allows the choice of a starting point for the fade function

//    fadeToBlackBy( test,    3, 16);               // these two lines are the same
      fadeToBlackBy(&test[0], 3, 16);               // fade only first three elements in the array
      fadeToBlackBy(&test[3], 1, 20);               // fade only the third element in the array

      if(test[0].r < 64){                           // pixels faded enough
        test[0]= CRGB(248, 11, 130);                // reload pixels
        test[1]= CRGB(221, 245, 6);
        test[2]= CRGB(112, 16, 236);
        test[3]= CRGB(16, 236, 53);
      }
    }
    memcpy(&leds[10], test,     4 * sizeof(CRGB));    // apply 4 pixels to leds[] array
    memcpy(&leds[50], &test[0], 4 * sizeof(CRGB));    // apply 4 pixels to leds[] array
    memcpy(&leds[80], &test[1], 3 * sizeof(CRGB));    // apply 3 pixels to leds[] array

    FastLED.show();                                   // send pixel data to the LED strip
  }
}
```